# set class name of div using its id in angular 4 and ngb-accordion

Tags: html, angular, angular5, bootstrap-accordion

I have ngb-accordion that has dynamic id's. Inside the ng-template i have div that changes class name depending on the state of the ngbPanelTitle if its open or not. Currently every row now changes to the same class when the row is clicked. How do I change the class name of this [class]="className" for a selected title/row?

below is the accordion

```
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true" (panelChange)="toggleAccordian($event)">
        <div *ngFor="let item of store.items">
            <ngb-panel id="static-{{item.id}}">
                <div class="accordion-head">
                    <ng-template class="super" ngbPanelTitle>
                        <div class="row heads">
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <div [class]="className" id="static-{{item.id}}" #someVar></div> &nbsp;<b>{{item.description}}</b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm"> {{item.summary}}</div>
                            <div class="col-sm"> {{item.person}}</div>
                            <div class="col-sm"> {{item.date | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a' }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
                </div>
                <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                    <b>Summary :</b> {{item.summary}}
                </ng-template>
            </ngb-panel>
        </div>
    </ngb-accordion>
```

Then my angular code below

```
    export class HistoryGridComponent implements OnInit {
  options: GridOptions;
  id: number;
  panelState: boolean;
  className: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, public store: MyStore) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.route.paramMap
          .map((params: ParamMap) => params.get('id'))
          .subscribe(id => {
              this.id = parseInt(id, 10);
              this.className = this.setClass();//set classname on page load
          });

  }

    //on click of the title this get fired
  public toggleAccordian(props: NgbPanelChangeEvent): void {
      this.panelState = props.nextState; // true === panel is toggling to an open state 
      // false === panel is toggling to a closed state
     props.panelId;    // the ID of the panel that was clicked

          this.className = this.setClass();

  }


    setClass() {
       this.className = this.panelState ? 'spriteUp' : 'spriteDown';
      return this.className;
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you're missing a question there. And also, please make a [mcve]

Comment: you could define a list of classes as an array and use it in your html for ngselect